# Python Number Guessing Game Need Help Avoiding Counting Duplicates in "Number of Guesses"

Tags: python

I am brand new to learning Python and am building a very simple number guessing game. The user guesses a number between 1-100, and are given feedback on whether their guess is too low or too high. When they guess the number correctly, the program tells them how many guesses they took. What I need help with: telling the user when they guessed a duplicate number if they have entered it already. I also want to exclude any duplicate guesses from the final guess count. What is the easiest way to do this?

Here is my game so far:

```
import random

print("Guess a number between 1-100")

the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input(""))
tries = 0

while guess != the_number:
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower")
    if guess < the_number:
        print("Higher")

    guess = int(input("Guess again: "))
    tries += 1
    if guess == the_number:
        print("You win! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
```

Comment: You know that if they guess it right on the first try it will never enter the loop and so they will never see the "You win" prints, right?  As for how to do what you asked, you'll have to keep track of all the guesses they've made in a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or even better a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) so it will "squash" duplicates for you. then check if the guess is already in the list

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the numbers guessed, only increasing if the user has not guessed a number already in our guessed set:

```
import random

print("Guess a number between 1-100")

the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 0
# store all the user guesses
guessed = set()

while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    # if the guess is in our guesses set, the user has guessed before
    if guess in guessed:
        print("You already guessed that number!")
        continue
    # will only increment for unique guessed
    tries += 1
    if guess == the_number:
        print("You win! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
        break
    elif guess > the_number:
        print("Lower")
    # if it's not == or >, it has to be <
    else:
        print("Higher")
    # add guess each time
    guessed.add(guess)
```

You also had some logic in regard to your ordering like taking a guess outside the loop which could have meant you never entered the loop if the user guessed first time.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should write the code.

```
import random

debug = True


def number_guessing():
    previous_guesses = set()
    tries = 0
    print("Guess a number between 1-100")
    random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    while True:
        guess = int(input())
        if guess in previous_guesses:
            print("You already tried that number")
            continue
        previous_guesses.add(guess)
        tries += 1

        if random_number < guess:
            print(f"Lower => previous attempts [{previous_guesses}] tries [{tries}]") if debug is True else None
        elif random_number > guess:
            print(f"Higher => previous attempts [{previous_guesses}] tries [{tries}]") if debug is True else None
        elif guess == random_number:
            print("You win! The number was", random_number)
            print(f"And it only took you {tries} attempt{'s' if tries>1 else ''}!\n")
            break


number_guessing()
```